# Disable auto run .exe file?

Tags: windows-server-2012, autorun

I run Windows Server 2012 and when I log in the *Open File* window appears and it wants to start a *.exe* file. Where can I view the start up folder and disable all the start ups? Note that I want to disable the *.exe* file and not programs.

Comment: Want to exe files are not executed at all?)) Well, you can. There are a number of ways, and why? Or do you want to disable autorun?

Comment: @STTR When I log in to automatically the Open File dialog opens and I want to remove that .exe file that was added to the startup folder/place.

Comment: @SimonZettervall: You're welcome, I posted it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) from Microsoft is naturally the utility "which has the most comprehensive knowledge of auto-starting locations of any startup monitor", and it supports Server 2003+.

[image: 1]